# How to reproduce the Picker 'shaded area' affect

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to figure out how to create the same effect as the Picker has in that shaded area indicating selection. I've created a UIScrollView, and the user is able to flip between things in it, but I want to clearly indicate what it is that they have selected in the same manner as the Picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a semi-transparent UIView above the scrollview at some fixed position. Having the items in the scrollview actually "snap" into position under the custom view would require a bit more logic, but it is doable. I haven't tried this approach before and it is pretty naive, but maybe others will have some better suggestions.

Comment: How do you do a semi-transparent UIView? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Set the opacity for the UIView.

Comment: For the "snap", all you need to do is to set the PagingEnabled property to true, and set a ContentSize on the UIScrollView, which is the size of one page of data, which in your case would be a rectangle around a number. You also probably want to enable Bounces = true, and hide the horizontal and vertial scroll indicators.